# UCDetector wrongly detecting @Autowired EJB Bean implementation class.

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0, aop

I am using UCDetector 1.9.0 to detect dead code.

I have a local EJB3 interface which is used in the bean definition and autowired it by name in another business delegate class.The implementation of the EJB3 runs fine without any problem.  Since the bean interface is referred in the spring context xml file and the business delegate class it is **wrongly flagging the implementation bean class as unused code**.

Is there any setting that could help in this case?

Any suggestions on other tools are also welcome. The purpose is to detect unused code in Spring / AOP Projects

Answer (score 1):

Use [UCDetector preferences](http://www.ucdetector.org/preferences.html)  "Classes implementing/extending".

Comment: it seems We need to add each and every class those we are using in our aplication?? If so it won't be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

UC Detector simply cannot do that. Although it has some preferences to ignore code (e.g. to ignore classes implementing a certain interface or to ignore code with a certain annotation), it doesn't work well for Spring. UC Detector will completely ignore those classes which is typically not what you want. If you use classes which will be auto-wired by Spring you only want to suppress the "Class XY has 0 references" warning, but you still want other warning (e.g. about the visibility of the class). If you tell UC Detector to ignore them, you will get nothing.

Comment: Any suggestions on any other tools?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am using UC Detector on my own in a Spring project and I just ignore the warnings I know better. Sorry.